# NullPointerException with JPA, Eclipselink and Guice

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, guice, guice-persist

I have a JpaController class like this:

```
public class JpaController
{
  @Inject private EntityManager em;

  @Transactional
  public void create(Message msg)
  {
    em.persist(msg);
  }
}
```

and I'm installing a `com.google.inject.persist.PersistFilter` (although not filtering through it because I'm not in an HTTP request at this point, it's a background thread).

I also install a `new JpaPersistModule(PU)`

The EntityManager is successfully populated I think (though I wouldn't be confident of this because the code doesn't reach that line).

The exception that gets thrown is from the interceptor for `@Transactional`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.getActivePersistenceContext(EntityManagerImpl.java:1712)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.begin(EntityTransactionImpl.java:49)
  at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.invoke(JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.java:62)
  at my code - the line that called controller.create(msg);
```

Libraries used:
EclipseLink 2.4.1,
guice 3.0,
guice-persist 3.0,
guice-jndi 3.0,
guice-servlet 3.0,
MySQL 5.1.25,
javax.persistence 2.0.4,
Jackson, activemq, lombok, joda-time, javax.mail, javax.inject, asm, jersey, log4j, jettison, jsr311.

Comment: I believe this error can only occur if the EM is closed after the getTransaction() call, since starting the transaction requires the EntityManager remain open, but I am not familiar with the setup to tell you why the EM would have been closed.  Perhaps provide the configuration and someone might be able to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite issues injecting directly an EntityManager, that could be closed, without connections,...

Instead of injecting an EntityManager, try to implement ths it  through a guice provider :

```
public class JpaController
{
  @Inject private Provider<EntityManager> _entityManagerProvider;

  @Transactional
  public void create(Message msg)
  {
    _entityManagerProvider.get().persist(msg);
  }
}
```

[Teorically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920400/jpa-2-eclipselink-caching-issue), emProvider.get() will always return a valid EntityManager instance througth JpaPersistModule

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your persistence unit failed to start/initialize, or is not configured correctly.

Enable logging on finest (in your persistence.xml) to see if any errors occurred on deployment.  Also try using a debugger to see what is null.